# RMarkdown: how to use results = 'asis' and fig.show = 'hold' together?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I would like to use `results = 'asis'` in a RMarkdown chunk option, to programmatically print section headings in a loop, as described [in the cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/results-asis.html).

I would also like to have multiple figures side-by-side using `fig.show = 'hold', out.width = '50%'` as also described [in the cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figures-side.html).

However when I try to combine both those options into one chunk, it doesn't work because it causes all the headings to print first, then all the plots at the end.

*Is there any way to programmatically create headings in a loop and show side-by-side figures at the same time?*

### Example of what I have tried

````
---
title: "fig.show asis reprex"
output: html_document
---

```{r, results = 'asis', fig.show = 'hold', out.width = '50%', echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE}
library(ggplot2)

for (i in 1:3) {
  cat(paste('\n\n# Column', i, 'of the wonderful mtcars dataset\n\n'))
  print(ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x = names(mtcars)[1])) + geom_boxplot())
  print(ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x = names(mtcars)[1])) + geom_histogram())
  
}
```
````

Sadly, I get this output, instead of having each header appear directly above the appropriate figures:

[image: bad result notebook output]

Comment: Just remove the `fig-show: hold` and try again. Figure should automatically be stacked side by side under each header, since the width is 50%.

Comment: @shafee your suggestion worked in the reprex, but in my actual document the figures do not appear side by side when `fig.show='hold'` is removed but `out.width='50%'` is kept. This may be because I used a for loop in my real code. I will edit this Q soon to make a better reprex that reproduces the behavior.